# the_posts_pagination() not working if I add wp_head() to header.php

Tags: plugins, functions, templates, archives

I have WordPress template my problem is with the_posts_pagination? its not showing in archive page I try to delete same functions to see what is the function to see.

when is delete wp_head() function from template header the_posts_pagination working, But wp_head() is recommended function to load WordPress header.

I try disable all plugins and no thing happen, I tried to create a new empty site with my template, but the problem remained even if the site was empty and without plugins.

I have put pictures of the functions?

I also have many themes with the same source code and they work fine
thank you.

[image: the_posts_pagination image]

[image: wp_head() image]

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running? Also, can you enable `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`, `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` in `wp-config.php` and see if any debug output is logged to `/wp-content/debug.log`. See [WP_DEBUG](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/setting-up-a-development-environment/#wp_debug)

Comment: Last version, and i will try

Comment: After add `define ( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`  This file -> `/wp-content/debug.log` not found.

Comment: Add `define ( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );` and tell me if you see any debug output printed to your screen? You might have a permission issue or other server related config sending your debug output to another file such as `error_log` or similar in root directory.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for help the problem was in `style.css` nav-pagination was have `position: fixed` and `top: -999`

Comment: No problem! I am glad that helped.